# Which Big Data analytics platform has most extensive GIS support?

Tags: software-recommendations, big-data, google-big-query, snowflake, amazon-redshift

I've recently had to deal with datasets that are simply too large to be efficiently processed using PostgreSQL and so I've turned to Google's BigQuery for those tasks. BigQuery, while offering exponentially faster processing of tables with rowcounts in the dozens of millions, has a much slimmer [library of spatial functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions). Support for SRID transformations and rasters are basically non-existent, and many of the QoL functions (like [orderingequals](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_OrderingEquals.html), [pointonsurface](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_PointOnSurface.html), [symdifference](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SymDifference.html)) don't exist in the standard library and might not easily be reconstructed using BQ's custom function creation options.

This can lead to weird platform gymnastics where stuff gets aggregated in BQ, pushed over to PostGIS for certain operations and then potentially even back to BQ for more processing. That's probably a temporary thing as BQ continues to improve its GIS capability, but it makes me wonder:

Which player in this field stands out from the competition in terms of geospatial capabilities?

I'm not looking for opinions, but explicit information like geometry and geography data type support, raster analysis support, processing speeds for spatial operation, the extent to which ST functions have been integrated with the platform, integration options with desktop and server-based geospatial software like QGIS, ArcGIS and GeoServer.

To clarify, big data analytics platforms, to me, include services that explicitly champion their ability to effectively handle very large datasets. These include Google BigQuery, Snowflake, Amazon Redshift, and several others.

Comment: I guess you'd be better off when researching on your own, especially when it comes to the support-part of your question.

Comment: Sure, but couldn't the same be said of any question asked on GIS SE? If the person asking would put enough research into the question, they'd be able to answer it themselves. I was curious to see if anyone had recently needed to to a capabilities analysis of these platforms for their organization, and their feedback on where these platforms stand right now, in a very rapidly moving industry.

Comment: Capability list compilation, especially in a "very rapidly moving industry" is off-charter for GIS SE. This is just going to invite marketing/spam for vendors who believe they "stand out from the competition". This wouldn't be off-topic in [Chat]

Comment: Maybe rephrase your question on "how to process efficiently very large datasets", you tried BigQuery it didn't work by lack of needed spatial fonction. this format should fit GIS SE

Comment: @J.R thanks, but that would lead to a lot of very specific questions lol. Maybe best as a chat on GIS systems as suggested by Vince.

Comment: I think a bigger problem with this question than it seeking opinions is that for any one trying to answer it they are in effect having to answer and weight the answers to multiple questions. If it’s a software recommendation that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange (or the GIS Chat Room).